# how to handle events using object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, i have an event object which collects information about an interaction by the user. Here the event might be a button click or page reload or click on a tabbed menu etc. Means any action on the page could be captured by this event object. Can any one please suggest me how to achieve this using Object oriented javascript. Like for example, see the below code snippet:

```
digitalEvent.event[n].eventInfo = {
    eventName: "Login",
    eventAction: "login",
    type: "click",
    loginLocation:"somelocation",
    timestamp: new Date()
}
```

This would be an object but on a page how to handle or capture events like click by a user etc.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There is a global jQuery Event (https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), perhaps you can tap into its prototype and do your custom stuff

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the following code will handle all events triggered for the window object. You might want to handle specific onkeydown keycodes. As for capturing page reload and retaining your object's value, you will need to store it inside a cookie or Local Storage on onbeforeunload.

```
for (var property in window) {
    var match = property.match(/^on(.*)/)
    if (match) { 
        window.addEventListener(match[1] ,function(event){
           console.log(event.type + " , " + event.timeStamp);
           //store any information inside the object
        }, false); 
    }
}
```